# Annotating a Sum results in None rather than zero

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I'm making a QA site that is similar to the page you're on right now.  I'm attempting to order answers by their score, but answers which have no votes are having their score set to None rather than 0.  This results in answers with no votes being at the bottom of the page below negatively ranked answers.  How can I make the annotated score be zero when there are no votes for an answer?

Here's my model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

Answer(models.Model):
    //some fields here
    pass

VOTE_CHOICES = ((-1, Down), (1, Up))

Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer)
    type = models.IntegerField(choices = VOTE_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (user, answer)
```

And here's my query:

```
answers = Answer.objects.filter(<something here>)
                        .annotate(score=Sum('vote__type'))
                        .order_by('-score')
```

edit: And to be clear, I'd like to do this in the query.  I know I could turn it into a list and then sort it in my python code, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: FYI, there is an open [Django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10929) about default values for `Sum()`.

Answer (score 209):

You can use the [`Coalesce` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce) from `django.db.models.functions` like:

```
answers = (Answer.objects
    .filter(<something here>)
    .annotate(score=Coalesce(Sum('vote__type'), 0))
    .order_by('-score'))
```

Comment: Ironically, I guess, this answer is at the bottom for me.

Comment: *IMPORTANT*
`coalesce` returns `null` if there are no rows found.

Unfortunately I have to find another solution

Comment: @EugeneKovalev Coalesce returns a default value if the queried value itself is null. It doesn't evaluate entire rows, right?

Comment: @EugeneKovalev Did you find a solution to `coalesce` returning `null` when there are no rows?

Comment: @kingraphaii nah, I didn't

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I managed to use Conditional Filters to make it work.

Comment: @EugeneKovalev What? No it does not.

Comment: @ruohola my bad I haven't put enough details in that comment. It depends on a DB that is being used, not on Django. I was using PostgreSQL back then.

Comment: @EugeneKovalev Any idea on PostgreSQL with zero rows ?

Comment: @EugeneKovalev could you edi your first comment, because has too many upvotes and the other comments are hide by default. This will help on the reading/finding answers.

Comment: One way to avoid getting `null` could be to move the filter query in the parameter `filter=<some query>` inside the `annotate` method instead of the `.filter` method of object itself.

Answer (score 7):

from django's documentation for [Coalesce](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce):

> Prevent an aggregate Sum() from returning None.
> The aggregate default argument uses Coalesce() under the hood.

So instead of using `Coalesce`, we can use the "default" argument:

```
answers = Answer.objects.filter(<something here>)
                    .annotate(score=Sum('vote__type', default=0))
                    .order_by('-score')
```

Comment: This should be marked as the top solution, neat and straight to the point

Comment: For some reason, this not working for me. I still see `None` even after adding `default=0`.

Answer (score -5):

What about you use custom `Manager`? For example:

```
AnswerManager(models.Manager):
    def all_with_score(self):
       qs = self.get_query_set().annotate(score=Sum('vote__type'))
       # Here, you can do stuff with QuerySet, for example
       # iterate over all Answers and set 'score' to zero if None.

Answer(models.Model):
    //some fields here
    objects = AnswerManager()
```

Then, you can use:

```
>>> answers = Answer.objects.all_with_score().order_by('-score')
```

Comment: The question asked how to replace the None values with 0 for the built in Sum aggregate function. This doesn't do that