# Annotating SUM aggregation function leading to 'None' value in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-aggregation

Doing my first real Django project, and need guidance.

**Background:**
My project is a reddit clone. Users submit links+text. Visitors upvote or downvote. There's a social_ranking algo, runs every ~2 mins as a background script, reranks all the submissions according to net votes and freshness of content. Fairly vanilla stuff.

**Problem:**
Ordering by `votes` isn't working correctly, because `votes` are being initialized as `None` instead of `0`. This causes submissions with `None` votes to rank below submissions with negative votes. I've debugged this issue for days - no luck.

**Specifics:**
I've over-ridden my model's model manager to annotate a `Sum` aggregation function to the query set, and then order the said query set by 'social rank' and votes.

Below is my **models.py**. I'm using `Django 1.5`, thus some stuff you see here may not correspond to 1.8 (e.g. `get_query_set` vs `get_queryset`):

```
class LinkVoteCountManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(LinkVoteCountManager, self).get_query_set().annotate(votes=Sum('vote__value')).order_by('-rank_score', '-votes') 

class Link(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField(_("Write something"))
    submitter = models.ForeignKey(User)
    submitted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    rank_score = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    url = models.URLField(_("Link"), max_length=250, blank=True)

    with_votes = LinkVoteCountManager() 
    objects = models.Manager() 

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return self.description

    def set_rank(self):
        # Based on reddit ranking algo at http://amix.dk/blog/post/19588
        epoch = datetime(1970, 1, 1).replace(tzinfo=None)
        netvotes = self.votes # 'NONE' votes are messing up netvotes amount.
        if netvotes == None:
            netvotes = 0
        order = log(max(abs(netvotes), 1), 10)
        sign = 1 if netvotes > 0 else -1 if netvotes < 0 else 0
        unaware_submission = self.submitted_on.replace(tzinfo=None)
        td = unaware_submission - epoch 
        epoch_submission = td.days * 86400 + td.seconds + (float(td.microseconds) / 1000000)
        secs = epoch_submission - 1432201843
        self.rank_score = round(sign * order + secs / 45000, 8)
        self.save()

class Vote(models.Model):
    voter = models.ForeignKey(User)
    link = models.ForeignKey(Link)
    value = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s gave %s to %s" % (self.voter.username, self.value, self.link.description)
```

If needed, the following are relevant sections from my **views.py**:

```
class LinkListView(ListView):
    model = Link
    queryset = Link.with_votes.all()
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LinkListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            voted = Vote.objects.filter(voter=self.request.user)
            links_in_page = [link.id for link in context["object_list"]]
            voted = voted.filter(link_id__in=links_in_page)
            voted = voted.values_list('link_id', flat=True)
            context["voted"] = voted
        return context

class LinkCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Link
    form_class = LinkForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        f = form.save(commit=False)
        f.rank_score=0
        f.with_votes = 0
        f.category = '1'
        f.save()
        return super(CreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Can anyone shed light on what I need to do to fix the "`None`" issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what if you set null=False keeping default=0?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Just hit the same wall, although I chose to ignore `None` entries by excluding them out of the results. Guess you don't want that.

BTW, this question has the same issue [Annotating a Sum results in None rather than zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160648/annotating-a-sum-results-in-none-rather-than-zero)

As for the solution other than using a custom sql as pointed out in that question's answer, you can use Django 1.8 instead and go for the solution pointed out in the ticket open in Django's bug tracker for over 6 years(!) https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10929

```
Coalesce(Sum('field'), 0)
```

So your manager would be:

```
class LinkVoteCountManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(LinkVoteCountManager, self).get_query_set().annotate(
            votes=Coalesce(Sum('vote__value'), 0)
        ).order_by(
            '-rank_score', 
            '-votes'
        )
```

PS: I have not tested the code, since I'm not using Django 1.8 myself.

Answer (score 9):

You could also replace the line

`netvotes = self.votes`

to

`netvotes = self.votes or 0`

and you can now remove the if statement.

What this does as in many other languages is to return the non [falsy](http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/10/17/true-lies-and-falsy-values-in-python-and-javascript/) value (None, 0, ""), or the last value, '0' in this particular case.